# Time dilation at the Innermost Stable Circular Orbit

Tags: general-relativity, angular-velocity, kerr-metric

According to general relativity the time dilation is given by following formular:

$d \tau = \sqrt{g_{\mu \nu} \dot{x^{\mu}} \dot{x^{\nu}}}$

If I'm interestet in the time dilation at the ISCO I set $\Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $dr=0$ so I get:

$d\tau = \sqrt{g_{tt} + g_{\phi t} \dot{\phi} + g_{\phi \phi} \dot{\phi}^2} dt$

But now I need $\dot{\phi}$ at the ISCO of a Kerr black hole but I only know the angular momentum:

$L= \frac{2mMar}{\rho²}sin²(\theta) \frac{dt}{d\tau}- \frac{m(r²+a²)²-m \Delta a²sin²(\theta)}{\rho²}sin²(\theta) \frac{d \phi}{d\tau}$

which includes only the derivation $\frac{d \phi}{d\tau}$ with respect to $\tau$ not $\frac{d \phi}{dt}$.

So how is it possible to calculate $\dot{\phi}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule. $$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{d\tau} \frac{d\tau}{dt}$$ Also your equations are wrong. $\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{g_{\mu \nu}\dot{x^\mu}\dot{x^\nu}}$